# Is there an efficient image format to display boolean values?

Tags: image, boolean, memory-efficient

If there is a two dimensional array of booleans, would there be an efficient way to represent this as an image and save this using minimal space? So just one bit for every pixel, having it either be black or white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you could put a bitmap header on a buffer and display it this way, you wont save any memory, but you will be able to view it... if you are looking to save space there are lots of lossless encoding techniques... huffman coding and lzw are some methods... some of those methods get grouped into formats like zip, bzip, gzip, deflate, etc

Answer (score 1):

My guess is no, because in an image, the color attribute of each pixel is represented by at least 8 bits. So you in effect are using an 8-bit byte to store a value which can be represented by one solitary bit (0 or 1).

In addition, there are other attributes that describe each pixel in an image, including alpha channel, opacity, and so on.

So, in short, although it may be visually pleasing to use images to store binary data, it would in fact be using way more storage space.

Most programming languages have native support for biinary data, and these provide much more efficient storage for them.